# Rabin Karp algorithm in java

Tags: java, rabin-karp

I am interested in implementing the Rabin-Karp algorithm to search for sub strings. Here is the algorithm i used: [algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TT6iV.png).

The code I made for the same is as below.
But output is blank. It says build successfully but gives no output...

```
package rabinkarp;

public class RabinKarp {

    final static int q = 101;
    final static int d = 256;
    public static void RabinKarpMatcher(String T,String p,int q,int d)
    {
        int n = T.length();
        int M = p.length();
        int H = 1,i,j;
        for (i = 0; i < M-1; i++)
            H = (H*d)%q;
        int P = 0;
        int t = 0;
        for(i = 0;i < M; i++)
        {
            P = (d*P+p.charAt(i))%q;
            t = (d*t+T.charAt(i))%q;
        }
        for(i = 0; i < n-M; i++)
        {
            if(P==t)
            {
                for(j = 0; j < M; j++)
                {
                    if(T.charAt(i+j)!=p.charAt(j))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(j==M)
                {
                    System.out.println("Pattern found at " + i+1);
                }

            }
            if(i < n-M)
            {
                t = (d*(t-T.charAt(i)*H)+T.charAt(i+M))%q;
                if(i <0)
                {
                    t = t+q;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = new String("ababaaabhahhhha");
        String pat = new String("ha");
        RabinKarpMatcher(text,pat,q,d);
    }

}
```

Comment: And what's your problem?

Comment: output is not comming

Comment: Would recommend running your code through check style to fix spacing issues, then attaching a debugger and stepping though it to see where its failing.